# How to use Casbin to setup dynamic RBAC with Beego?

Tags: go, rbac, beego, casbin

How do I setup dynamic RBAC using [Casbin](https://github.com/casbin/casbin) with [Beego](http://beego.me)?
I am using MySQL database via Beego ORM and able to login. However, I want to setup roles and permissions.

I also explored [`gorbac`](https://mikespook.com/2017/04/how-to-persist-gorbac-instance/) but I am interested to use Casbin.

Answer (score 1):

There's an authorization middleware for Beego here: https://github.com/casbin/beego-authz. You can read the README.md to know how to do it. And for your requirement:

1. Please use the `Xorm Adapter` or `Gorm Adapter` to store Casbin policy into MySQL. We also have `Beego ORM Adapter` but it has some limitations.
2. You want to setup roles, so you can use Casbin's RBAC model. You can start with the official RBAC example (model + policy). If your resource is just the RESTful path, you can also refer to the `RESTful` example.

Comment: Thanks @Yang Luo. Do you have an example repository where I can look up the implementation? I am new to Beego and casbin and just trying it out.

Comment: The Beego middleware itself already contains an example, see the main.go file: https://github.com/casbin/beego-authz/blob/master/main.go

Comment: Any persistence example?

Comment: See this example: https://github.com/aixj1984/website-gateway/blob/299e1ea91af488e434a3c0f475270484224be13e/enforcer/casbin.go#L9